# Writing the most general form resistivity tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, tensor-calculus, mathematics

I am unsure as to write the resistivity tensor in the most general form in 3 dimensions. Using the following equation. Please can someone explain?

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{ne}(\vec{j}\times\vec{B})+\frac{m}{ne^2\tau}\vec{j}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the  vector equation
$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{ne}(\vec{j}\times\vec{B})+\frac{m}{ne^2\tau}\vec{j}$$
in components. This gives
$$\begin{pmatrix}E_x\\E_y\\E_z\end{pmatrix}
=\frac{1}{ne}\begin{pmatrix}j_yB_z-j_zB_y\\j_zB_x-j_xB_z\\j_xB_y-j_yB_x\end{pmatrix}
 +\frac{m}{ne^2\tau}\begin{pmatrix}j_x\\j_y\\j_z\end{pmatrix}$$

Then you need to further rewrite this until it has the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}E_x\\E_y\\E_z\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
\rho_{xx}&\rho_{xy}&\rho_{xz}\\
\rho_{yx}&\rho_{yy}&\rho_{yz}\\
\rho_{zx}&\rho_{zy}&\rho_{zz}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}j_x\\j_y\\j_z\end{pmatrix}$$
I leave the missing steps to find the resistivity matrix $\rho$ to you as an exercise.

Comment: Reading this question I thought it was about the tensor resistivity of an anisotropic crystal.